# How to manage Ontology classes in Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, owl, ontology

I have a very simple Ontology which has only Classes and Subclasses.

I need a way to access the classes and subclasses name's knowing what is the relation between them (x is subclass of y, x is subsubclass of z, etc...).

I've been using the library Ontospy to open owl files in a structured way but couldn't find functions that helps me doing what I need.

Using an Ontology file (.owl) I want to create a window full of checkboxes illustrating the Ontology in a tree way just like this:
[image]

There is a method in the Ontospy library named "printCLassTree()" which prints all classes in a tree form using stdout.
if I could get the output of this method in a string or a list that would help me a lot.

Comment: What would you want to display when the class hierarchy isn't a tree?  E.g., when you have "D < C; D < B; C < A; B < A" (where "<" means "is a subclass of")?

Comment: I didn't get what you mean, the class hierarchy will always be a tree in my case. Every class will always be subclass of some other class, with the "first class" being Thing

Comment: "the class hierarchy will always be a tree in my case" OK, but you didn't say that in the question, so *we* didn't have a way to know that.  Class hierarchies don't have to be trees in OWL, so it's not a given in general.